# pandas: make a date histogram, given a start and end date?

Tags: pandas

I have this data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'start_date': ['2019/12/01 01:00:00', '2019/12/05 01:00:00', 
                                  '2019/12/01 01:00:00', '2019/12/01 01:00:00'],
                   'end_date': ['2019/12/05 10:00:00', '2019/12/09 10:00:00', 
                                '2019/12/11 10:00:00', '2019/12/09 01:00:00'],
                   'campaign_id' : [1,2,3,4]})
```

I'd like to plot the number of campaigns active each day from 2019/12/01 to 2019/12/11.

How can I do this? It's like a histogram, but by dates - but with multiple dates for each row.

I've got as far as converting the columns to timestamps:

```
df.start_date = df.start_date.astype('datetime64[ns]')
df.end_date = df.start_date.astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

Perhaps I need a new column that is `pd.date_range`, then I'll be able to do some clever pandas grouping...?

```
df["date_range"] = pd.date_range(df.start_date, df.end_date)
```

But that gives me an error.

I guess a more manual approach would be to make a new dataframe with a row for each day, then a histogram of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
pd.concat([
    pd.Series(x.campaign_id, index=pd.date_range(x.start_date, x.end_date, freq='D'))
    for i, x in df.iterrows()
]).groupby(level=0).value_counts().unstack('date').plot.bar()
```

Or this:

```
df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date']).dt.normalize()
df['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_date']).dt.normalize()

(df.assign(dummy=1)
   .merge(pd.DataFrame({'dummy':1,
                        'date': pd.date_range('2019-12-01', '2019-12-11', freq='D')}),
          on='dummy'
         )
   .query('start_date<=date<=end_date')
   .groupby('date')['campaign_id']
   .value_counts()
   .unstack('date')
   .plot.bar()
)
```

Output:

[image]

Or remove `'date'` inside `unstack()` to get counts by date:

[image]

Or if you are interested in the total daily events:

```
(df.assign(dummy=1)
   .merge(pd.DataFrame({'dummy':1,
                        'date': pd.date_range('2019-12-01', '2019-12-11', freq='D')}),
          on='dummy'
         )
   .query('start_date<=date<=end_date')
   .groupby('date')['campaign_id']
   .count()
   .plot.bar()
)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: now that i think about it i think first you need to figure out max and min start,end dates and maybe resample the df and plot it that way? it's actually a difficult dataset. nice solution tho.

Comment: @Datanovice OP does mention specific date range. Although the first solution does not need max and min start/end.

Comment: Oh - so close! I'd like the date on the x axis and the count on the y axis, so a histogram by day. Sorry, should have specified that (will update question).

Comment: @Richard remove `'date'` inside `unstack()` in either solution.

Comment: Epic! Thank you!